# I Have Two Versions of Java?

Tags: java

I currently have the 3s and 64 bit versions of java. This is causing some errors, and I want to get rid of the 32 bit version. What do I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to location **/usr/lib/jvm** and find the 32-bit folder by reading its docs and readme etc.
Then remove the folder of 32-bit Java version. you must have to be root to remove.

Also remove the environement variable path of 32-bit Java, type **env** at Terminal and see **JAVA_HOME** and similar to this one.
For example if you want to remove **JAVA_HOME_32**, you would type at terminal with root permission.

`env --unset=JAVA_HOME_32`

Comment: I can't find the 32 bit folder, where is it normally located

Comment: Never mind, when trying `java -d32` in the terminal, it says it isn't available. I must have uninstalled it.